# Returning a Nvarchar from a function When the Return value is 0 then other numeric value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

I Have a Function That Returns A Value From a Table when Using an ID

When Running This with the Value In the Database equalling '00' it returns the Value as 0

This Is the Function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSystemParameter]
(
    @Parameter nvarchar(50)
)

RETURNS nvarchar AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @return nvarchar(50)


        SELECT @return = [ParameterValue] FROM dbo.[SystemParameters] WHERE [ParameterName] = @Parameter

RETURN @return

END
```

When Selecting Value 
    `Select dbo.GetSystemParameter(<ParameterName>)`

Returns 0 instead of '00'
how can I get the Value to Return the 00 not the 0

Tank you in advance 
James

Comment: Tag your DBMS. What datatype is ParameterValue?

Comment: Change `RETURNS nvarchar` to `RETURNS nvarchar(<a sensible length>)`?

Comment: ParameterValue  parameter is NvarChar(50)

Comment: Thank you Richard that Works As Expected now

Answer (score 2):

The character types without a length use default lengths.  You have declared your stored procedure to return `nvarchar(1)`.  You should *always* use lengths with these types in SQL Server:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSystemParameter] (
    @Parameter nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(50) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return nvarchar(50);

    SELECT @return = [ParameterValue]
    FROM dbo.[SystemParameters]
    WHERE [ParameterName] = @Parameter;

    RETURN @return;
END;
```